# Vulkan - scissor calculations for negative viewport?

Tags: vulkan

If I'm using a negative viewport in Vulkan to flip to OpenGL orientation, should I do something to scissor calculations too if I'm expecting behavior similar to OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scissor rectangles are specified in framebuffer coordinates, which are the post-viewport coordinates of a fragment. So even if you negate the viewport rectangles, the scissor boxes won't need to change.

Of course, that means you *don't* get OpenGL behavior. But it shouldn't be difficult to do some simple match from OpenGL coordinates to Vulkan framebuffer coordinates.